# Doctrine 2.5 Embeddable: "Unknown Column"

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a User class that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 **/
class User {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="string")
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Password user's password
     * @Embedded(class="Acme\Users\Password")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var Email user's email address
     * @Embedded(class="Acme\Users\Email")
     */
     private $email;

    /* .... More .... */
}
```

And a Password class that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Embeddable
 */
class Password {
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password = NULL; 
}
```

When I try to find a user with this:

```
$this->repository->findOneBy([
    "email.email" => $email->toString()
]);
```

I'm getting errors like this:

```
Next exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException' with message 'An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.password AS password_2, t0.email_email AS email_email_3 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.email_email = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["jason@email.com"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.password' in 'field list'' in /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php(116): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception oc...', Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException))
#1 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(836): Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver), Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException), 'SELECT t0.id AS...', Array)
#2 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php(715): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT t0.id AS...', Array, Array)
#3 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php(196): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->load(Array, NULL, NULL, Array, NULL, 1, NULL)
#4 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/app/Acme/Users/DoctrineUserRepository.php(42): Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->findOneBy(Array)
#5 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/app/Acme/Users/Commands/AttemptSignInCommandHandler.php(15): Acme\Users\DoctrineUserRepository->findByEmail(Object(Acme\Users\Email))
#6 /Users/jason/Workspace/Personal/acme-bdd/vendor/league/tactician/src/HandlerCommandBus.php(55): Acme\Users\Commands\AttemptSignInCommandHandler->handleAttemptSignInCommand(Object(Acme\Users\Commands\AttemptSignInCommand))
```

I have these packages installed:

```
$ composer show -i | grep doctrine
doctrine/annotations              dev-master b5202eb Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                    dev-master dbeacc7 Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections              dev-master c63f2e6 Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                   dev-master 56360cc Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                     2.5.x-dev 67c4701  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/inflector                dev-master e5eaf8c Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator             dev-master 3d9669e A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                    dev-master 83893c5 Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/migrations               dev-master 1ac14fa Database Schema migrations using Doctrine DBAL
doctrine/orm                      dev-master 4a05e19 Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything right. Any help on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an incompatible version of PHP. I upgraded to the newest version and the problem went away.